# Possible to generate yearly archives?

Tags: ee2

Are there any plugins that make it possible to have yearly archives in EE? I'm talking about something like the current archives-by-month (January, February, etc. with the ability to paginate), but listing all entries posted in a full calendar year. I'm looking at moving to a responsive design, and want the date-based archives in the top menu like they are now...but I would love the option to link to a paginated template that lists all entries in a given calendar year (all entries in 2011, all entries in 2012, all entries in 2013...and so forth.) That would really shorten the top nav a LOT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, [Low Yearly Archives](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-yearly-archives) should work for you, in combination with the native channel:entries tag. If you don't use the `{months}{/months}` variable pair to output the months, but just use the years to link to something like `/such/obsessive/distractions/2014`, then you could simply use [the `year=""` parameter](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#year-month-day) to output entries for that year.

Comment: I currently use the native channel:entries tag to display the entries on that template - so I'm partially there, I think. But when you say "use the year parameter to output entries for that year"...sorry, I'm not following. The tag+parameters I currently use on the distractions template is exp:channel:entries channel="spc-content" orderby="date" sort="desc" limit="10" show_future_entries="no" paginate="bottom" rdf="off" status="open|Featured" Would I need to create separate templates for each year, and add in the year parameter?

Comment: Just use `year="{segment_4}"` where the segment variable points to the year in the URI. Also add `dynamic="no"` to make sure EE shows you what you tell it to show.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for? http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-yearly-archives

Comment: I've downloaded that and tried it out. It generates your archives separated into years, but it just links to your existing monthly-archive templates. I currently have monthly archives at http://www.sparklecrackcentral.com/such/obsessive/distractions/2014/03 (for example) I want to have a template that can display all archives for a given year ie http://www.sparklecrackcentral.com/such/obsessive/distractions/2014 (but EE currently does not have this functionality.)

Answer (score 0):

You could do that kind of archive using `stash` `match` and `against` parameters and pagination.

Have a look at the example here: https://gist.github.com/croxton/6219973

Answer (score 0):

You can filter entries by using a year in the URL: mysite.com/archives/2012

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="my channel" year="{segment_2}"}
// show all entries from year in URL
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Here's the documentation: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#id68